# AVplayerItem isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp but not really and video stops buffer

Tags: avfoundation, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avplayeritem

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    self.isPlayerReady(self.playerViewController?.player)

    if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.isPlaybackBufferEmpty){
        print("empty listener")
    }

    if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp){
        print("keepup change \(String(describing: playerViewController?.player?.currentItem?.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp))")
        if (playerViewController?.player?.currentItem?.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp == true) {
            print("tried to play")
                self.playerViewController?.player?.play()
                print( self.playerViewController?.player?.reasonForWaitingToPlay)
                print("buffer empty? \(self.playerViewController?.player?.currentItem?.isPlaybackBufferEmpty)")
                print("player rate \(self.playerViewController?.player?.rate)")
                print(self.playerViewController?.player?.currentItem?.error)

       }
   }
}
```

I am adding the above observer to the playerItem, what I found is that it shows PlayerItemlikelyToKeepup very early when the buffer duration is only like 4 or 5. And when it tries to play, it stays in the black screen and no more buffer will be load since the observer not getting any loadrange update. And reasonForWaitingToPlay is AVPlayerWaitingToMinimizeStallsReason.

How do I avoid this state? Thanks much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

try to set `automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27199862)

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri: I can’t speak to whether or not this is a _useful_ or even _correct_ answer, but [it is an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue).